# How to set function search_click() more than two request_url

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know how to set function `search_click()` more than two `request_url`.

I have a `function search_click` as below, and I have three user types with different `request_url`:

```
function search_click() {
  var type = $('#jsSelectOption').attr('data-value'),
    keywords = $('#search_keywords').val(),
    request_url = '';
  if (keywords == "") {
    return
  }
  if (type == "test") {
    request_url = "/admin?keywords=" + keywords
  } else if (type == "user") {
    request_url = "/admin/user?keywords=" + keywords
  }
}
```

I tried to change the code above with the one below, but it doesn't work.

```
function search_click() {
  var type = $('#jsSelectOption').attr('data-value'),
    keywords = $('#search_keywords').val(),
    request_url = '';
  if (keywords == "") {
    return
  }
  if (type == "test") {
    request_url = "/admin?keywords=" + keywords
    request_url = "/admin_a?keywords=" + keywords
    request_url = "/admin_b?keywords=" + keywords
  } else if (type == "user") {
    request_url = "/admin/user?keywords=" + keywords
    request_url = "/admin_a/user?keywords=" + keywords
    request_url = "/admin_b/user?keywords=" + keywords
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by **more than two request_url**? What do you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

just use request_url as an array `[]` and push in it all  your url

see below snippet :

```js
function search_click() {
  var type = $('#jsSelectOption').val(),
    keywords = $('#search_keywords').val(),
    //here you declar your var as an array .
    request_url = [];
  if (keywords == "") {
    return
  }
  
  if (type == "test") {
    request_url.push("/admin?keywords=" + keywords);
    request_url.push("/admin_a?keywords=" + keywords);
    request_url.push("/admin_b?keywords=" + keywords);
  } else if (type == "user") {
    request_url.push("/admin/user?keywords=" + keywords);
    request_url.push("/admin_a/user?keywords=" + keywords);
    request_url.push("/admin_b/user?keywords=" + keywords);
  }
  
  alert("values = \n"+request_url.toString().split(',').join("\n"))
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="keyword" id="search_keywords" />

<select id="jsSelectOption" >
  <option ></option>
  <option >test</option>
  <option >user</option>
</select>

<button onclick="search_click()">search</button>
```

Comment: Hi Boo, thank you so much for prompt reply, the user type of some users are admin, admin_a and admin_b in the meantime.........it doesn't work........

Comment: could you explain more §? what does not work , and what do you mean users are .... ?

Comment: When I send a request of `"/admin_a?keywords=" + keywords` ,the url is no reaction......it didn't work.

Comment: so this is not related to your current question ? in the console the what's the req url ? where is the part where you post to urls ?

Comment: This is related to my current question, in the console the url is /admin_a？keywords＝'Username' or 'Department' etc. Keywords, post them in base.html

Comment: show the code you post your data ? and what 's the http code returned when quering these urls .

Comment: my code and data are similar like this link's, the difference is I changed code according to yours https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/32753535